# Resuming interrupted spinrite session

Tags: hard-drive, spinrite

Everytime I interrupt my spinrite session, it prompt me with a percentage telling me that I could resume the session at the point of interrupt, this is all great but I never knew how to resume it.

As the drive get larger and larger, more often than usual my spinrite would complete it stuff overnight like it use to.

Can someone please tell me how I could resume it with the percentage i was prompted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [manual](https://www.grc.com/files/sr5_manual.pdf).

> **Command Line Options**
>
> SpinRite may be started by following the “SpinRite” command with a
>   number of optional “command line” keywords to cause its normal
>   operation to be altered in a number of ways.
>
> ...
>
> `Resume`
>
> When operating under “Auto” mode, SpinRite normally ignores
>   whether any partitions might have been interrupted in the past and
>   performs its work from the beginning of each hard disk partition, rather
>   than resuming where the prior work was suspended. The “Resume”
>   keyword causes SpinRite to pick up where it left off from the point of
>   interruption on those partitions that had work suspended.
>
> *Example*
>
> The command line below will run SpinRite on partitions C: and D:,
>   resuming operation on those partitions that had previously been
>   suspended at depth level 7, without requiring interaction from the user:
>
> `A:SPINRITE Auto Resume Drive C: D: Level 7 (Enter)`

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean I don't have the specify the percentage... cause that where I got confuse when I read the manual, I got the impression that the figure is needed.

I will try that. Thanks again.

Comment: No problems. It looks like you don't have to specify the percentage. I imagine SpinRite stores this information "somewhere".

Comment: Just find out there is a way to resume from the interrupted point (%) from right inside the spinrite user interface.

After selected the drive, normally we would press [Enter] to begin, but if we press Shift+[Enter] instead, we will be prompted to input the percentage we left off. Very useful.